# rails mass update column by inserting value calculated from other columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am making a sports leaderboard in **rails** and trying to mass assign a column with values calculated from other columns. Following is the names of the columns: `:pts`, `:games_played`, and `:pts_per_game`. The first two already have values assigned and I want to insert value into the last one by *dividing :pts by :games_played*. So I went to rails console and tried

```rb
PlayerLeaderboard.update_all(pts_per_game: pts/games_played)
```

But I get this output with NoMethodError

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `pts' for main:Object
    from (irb):24
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/AYL/Dropbox/workspace/rails/krossover/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/AYL/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'irb(main):025:0>
```

The weird thing is I tried this approach before and it worked. I just switched my development db from sqlite3 to postgres and re-seeded data. It seems very unlikely to me that switching db is the reason for this error; I must have missed something.
I also tried `update_column`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is treating `pts` and `games_played` as local variables or methods on `self`. There are no such methods, hence the error.

You want columns so you need to send a bit of SQL into `update_all` instead of a Ruby hash:

```
PlayerLeaderboard.update_all('pts_per_game = pts / games_played')
```

Presumably `pts` and `games_played` are integer columns so you're going to have truncation problems here. If that's what you want (i.e. `5 / 3` being `1`) then there's nothing to worry about. If your `pts_per_game` is floating point, then you'll need to throw a cast in the mix:

```
PlayerLeaderboard.update_all('pts_per_game = cast(pts as float) / games_played')
PlayerLeaderboard.update_all('pts_per_game = pts::float / games_played')
```

The `cast` is standard SQL, the `::` syntax is PostgreSQL-specific.

If your `pts_per_game` is an integer and you want it rounded, then you'll have to say so:

```
PlayerLeaderboard.update_all('pts_per_game = round(cast(pts as float) / games_played)')
```

If negative values are possible then you'll need to use `ceil` or `floor` instead of `round` to choose which direction your negative values should be rounded.

If you have zeros in `games_played` then you'll need to do two updates and decide what `pts_per_game` should be when there haven't been any games, zero and NULL would be reasonable choices I suppose:

```
PlayerLeaderboard.where(:games_played => 0).update_all(...)
PlayerLeaderboard.where.not(:games_played => 0).update_all(:pts_per_game => 0)
```

If you're going with NULL for `pts_per_game` when there aren't any games then you only need the first `update_all` since new columns are NULL by default.

Comment: How can I avoid `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DivisionByZero: ERROR:  division by zero` error?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with ActiveRecord:

```
PlayerLeaderboard.update_all("pts_per_game = pts/games_played")
```